# How to use an alertview to make a countdown ios

Tags: ios, swift

For example, I want to make a timer, and the remaining time will be showed in the alertview. After each Nstimer update, the number in the alertview will minus 1, when the number equals to 0, it will disappear automatically. So how to realize that in code.(swift)

Comment: Have you made any attempt?  You can display an alert view and update its title and text properties ina timer method, finally dismissing it.

Comment: A UIAlertView is an Apple component. Have you thought about building your own custom UIAlertView instead?

Comment: @Dominic It is trivial to do with a UIAlertView. No need to make your own unless you don't like the appearance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727474/how-can-i-display-a-popup-message-in-swift-that-disappears-after-3-seconds-or-ca/36731388#36731388

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know swift, so here is Obj-C code (which I believe you can convert to swift easily).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertView* alertView;
@property (nonatomic) int remainingSeconds;
//...

self.remainingSeconds = 10;
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something will happen in %d seconds", self.remainingSeconds];
self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some title"
                                            message:msg
                                           delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   otherButtonTitle:@"Ok"];
[self.alertView show];
```

Schedule a timer with 1 second of interval.

```
- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.remainingSeconds--;
    if (self.remainingSeconds == 0) {
         //dismiss alertview
         return;
    }
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Something will happen in %d seconds", self.remainingSeconds];      
    [self.alertView setMessage:msg];
}
```

Please note that this is fast written code directly in StackOverflow's editor, so some syntax errors is possible.